# How can I undo change to all lines of a SVN managed file?

Tags: svn

by accident, I changed the line endings of a *.c file that is managed by SVN and checked it in. It's not a problem to undo the change itself, BUT: when I run `svn annotate` now, the whole file looks as if I have created/changed every line... So some part if its history is hardly accessible...

How can I undo that unfortunate change? I think a "backwards merge" will still result in "I have changed everything" :s ...

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky that my changes were only in a feature branch. So what I did was:

Create a patch with my changes, without regard to line endings:

```
svn diff -x --ignore-eol-style --old  ^/trunk --new ^/branches/feature > ~/screwed-linenedings.patch
```

Then I deleted my feature branch, made a new branch from trunk and applied my patch. (After I applied the patch, I detected that cygwins `patch` changed the line endings of the patched files :(, but this time *before* I committed anything).